# Mensagens dialog disparadas da ViewModel por meio do DialogCoordinator

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dialog, mvvm

Me deparei com um problema trabalhando em um projeto WPF onde utilizo "MVVM Light Toolkit" e "MahApps.Metro".

Estou tentando aproveitar o recurso "DialogCoordinator" disponibilizado pelo "MahApps.Metro" para disparar as mensagens dialog das minhas ViewModels. No entanto, ao executar o método "ShowMessageAsync" o sistema está interrompendo a execução sem disparar nenhuma Exception ou mensagem que seja. Toda a configuração foi realizada conforme a documentação e não consigo identificar o motivo de não estar funcionando.

Segue códigos relacionados.

Atributos XAML necessários:

```
xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
```

Construtor do ViewModelLocator registrando o DialogCoordinator utilizado pela MainViewModel:

```
static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
            }
            else
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            }

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogCoordinator, DialogCoordinator>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        }
```

Construtor da MainViewModel:

```
public MainViewModel(IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator)
        {
            _dialogCoordinator = dialogCoordinator;            
        }
```

RelayCommand responsável por disparar a mensagem:

```
public RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs> ClosingWindow
        {
            get
            {
                return _closingWindow
                    ?? (_closingWindow = new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(ExecuteClosingWindow));
            }
        }
        private RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs> _closingWindow;
        private async void ExecuteClosingWindow(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsQuitConfirmation) return;

            var result = await _dialogCoordinator.ShowMessageAsync(this, "Teste", "Teste", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative, new MetroDialogSettings
            {
                AffirmativeButtonText = "OK",
                NegativeButtonText = "CANCELAR",
                AnimateShow = true,
                AnimateHide = false
            });            

            if (result == MessageDialogResult.Negative)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Identifiquei o motivo. É tão simples que chega a ser bobo.
Este RelayCommand está sendo disparado no evento Closing da minha MainWindow. Devido a aplicação estar bastante performática e o método ser assíncrono, o evento concluiu paralelamente sua operação antes que a mensagem fosse disparada.